# projection of one column from fs.files

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to execute this query:

```
db.fs.files.find({}, {filename: 1, _id: 0 })
```

using spring-data-mongodb (get only all files names).

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*option 1*

```
DBCollection fsCollection = template.getCollection("fs.files");
fsCollection.setObjectClass(null);
DBCursor cursor = fsCollection.find(new BasicDBObject(), new BasicDBObject("filename", 1).append("_id", 0));

while (cursor.hasNext()){
     final DBObject object = cursor.next();
     String filename = object.get("filename")

}
```

*option 2*

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate template;

@Document(collection="fs.files")
public class GridFsFile{

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    public ObjectId getId() { return id; }

    private String filename;
    public String getFilename() { return filename; }
}

Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("filename").exclude("_id");
template.find(query, GridFsFile.class)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but both options didn't work. In both I get exception: Can't load partial GridFSFile file. I found in source code in GridFSFile.java something like this: 
'public void markAsPartialObject(){
        throw new RuntimeException( "can't load partial GridFSFile file" );
}'. So I think it is not supported yet for java.

Comment: Which template are u using? Its working perfectly for me by the way

Comment: I'm using MongoTemplate. Do you have a piece of code with data extraction from DBCursor?

Comment: "i found in source code in GridFSFile.java"...why are you getting back `GridFsFileResul`t? you should use `MongoTemplate`, not `GridFsTemplate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73738/discussion-between-marcinp-and-royb).